# x86 Procedure Call Memory Allocation

Tags: c, assembly, struct, x86, att

So I have a problem from my textbook (Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective Problem 3.64):

It gives code like this:

```
typedef struct {
 int a;
 int *p;
} str1;

typedef struct {
 int sum;
 int diff;
} str2;

str2 word_sum(str1 s1) {
 str2 result;
 result.sum = s1.a + *s1.p;
 result.diff = s1.a - *s1.p;
 return result;
}

int prod(int x, int y) {
 str1 s1;
 str2 s2;
 s1.a = x;
 s1.p = &y;
 s2 = word_sum(s1);
 return s2.sum * s2.diff;
}
```

and then the assembly code for the prod & word_sum functions:

```
1 word_sum:
2  pushl %ebp
3  movl %esp, %ebp
4  pushl %ebx
5  movl 8(%ebp), %eax
6  movl 12(%ebp), %ebx
7  movl 16(%ebp), %edx
8  movl (%edx), %edx
9  movl %ebx, %ecx
10 subl %edx, %ecx
11 movl %ecx, 4(%eax)
12 addl %ebx, %edx
13 movl %edx, (%eax)
14 popl %ebx
15 popl %ebp

1 prod:
2  pushl %ebp
3  movl %esp, %ebp
4  subl $20, %esp
5  leal 12(%ebp), %edx
6  leal -8(%ebp), %ecx
7  movl 8(%ebp), %eax
8  movl %eax, 4(%esp)
9  movl %edx, 8(%esp)
10 movl %ecx, (%esp)
11 call word_sum
12 subl $4, %esp
13 movl -4(%ebp), %eax
14 imull -8(%ebp), %eax
15 leave
16 ret
```

And it asks why prod allocates 20 bytes on the stack in the assembly code line 4.

I can see that it would allocate 8 bytes each for str1 and str2 but I have no idea what the 5th 4-byte memory allocation would be.

Also, would you guys have any recommendations (videos, articles, blog posts) on learning x86 stack frame structure and procedure calls? Very lost in my Computer Architecture course at the moment.

Comment: I think this code is a little bit optimized. What is the calling convention? cdecl?

Comment: @CollinDauphinee it doesn't say but I assume it is cdecl because the textbook told us that eax, ecx and edx are caller saved, which is what cdecl has.

Comment: Yes, I know what this code is doing, I'm just trying to figure out the best way to explain it. This is a terrible problem, unless you were given `word_sum` and didn't include it in the question.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee yes we were given word_sum. My apologies, I thought we didn't need it to answer the question. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The allocations are 8 bytes for `s1`, 8 bytes for `s2`, and 4 bytes to pass `word_sum` an address to store it's result at.

---

How did I figure this out?

If we look at the top of `prod`, we see:

```
5  leal 12(%ebp), %edx
6  leal -8(%ebp), %ecx
7  movl 8(%ebp), %eax
```

Lines 5 and 7 are the only instructions accessing our caller's stack frame, so they must be grabbing `x` and `y`. We know that we're storing a pointer to `y` and line 5 is a `lea` instruction, so we can assume that EDX holds `&y` and EAX holds `x`. This still leaves ECX, which holds a pointer to something in our stack frame.

Moving on, we see that it's storing EAX, EDX, and ECX on our stack, and then calling `word_sum`:

```
8  movl %eax, 4(%esp)
9  movl %edx, 8(%esp)
10 movl %ecx, (%esp)
11 call word_sum
```

We know that EAX and EDX hold the values that need to be stored in `s1`. We know that `s1` will be passed to `word_sum`, and arguments are passed at the top of the stack. Lines 8 and 9 are storing EAX and EDX very close to the top of the stack, so we can assume this is `s1`.

Functions that return a struct *expect extra pointer to be passed at the top of the stack*. This is the address that it should store it's return value at. The only other thing we're storing on the top of the stack is ECX, and we know that we're storing the result of `word_sum` in `s2`, so ECX must be a pointer to `s2`.

We've now surmised what each register holds; EAX is `x`, EDX is `&y`, and ECX is `&s2`.

If we look lower, we can confirm our expectations:

```
13 movl -4(%ebp), %eax
14 imull -8(%ebp), %eax
```

We know that the result of this function is `s2.sum * s2.diff`. There's an `imul` instruction, and we're multiplying `s2.sum` by `s2.diff`, so EBP-8 must point to `s2.sum` and EBP-4 must point to `s2.diff`.

If we backtrack to line 6, we see that EBP-8 was stored in ECX, which we correctly suspected was a pointer to `s2`.

---

In general, debugging problems like this is almost entirely using your knowledge of the code that generated the assembly to make educated guesses, and then using process of elimination to confirm that your guess is correct.

Comment: Could you explain the 4 bytes to preserve ECX? Does it have something to do with it being caller saved?

Comment: Hopefully you can understand this. This is a hard problem to explain, because there are a few optimizations going on here.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed edit. I just had a few more questions if you wouldn't mind answering:

1. Why is it only the address of s2 and not of s1 as well?

2. How do you know which args are stored in which registers?

Comment: I'm actually wrong, it's _not_ preserving the registers, because it doesn't need to them after the call. The extra 4 bytes is the address that the callee should store it's return value in. See the (hard to follow) explanation.